# No files found in archive when renaming files

Tags: perl

This program reads a list of files from the directory specified on the command line, creates an array of hashes, where each file has key path, size, and sha256sum.

I am trying to create a gzipped tarball of the files, where each files is name the checksum appended with the file's original extension.

I create a gzipped tarball of the files successfully. However, when I try to use Archive::Tar's rename method, I am met with this error:

No such file in archive: '/path/to/file1.txt' at ./program.pl line 62. This error repeats for each file in the archive.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use File::Spec qw(catfile rel2abs);
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
use Archive::Tar;
use Archive::Tar::File;

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my $url = $ARGV[1];
my @AoH;
my @checksumfiles;
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;
my $archive = "archive.tar.gz";

opendir DIR, $dir or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!\n";
chdir $dir or die "cannot navigate to dir $dir: $!\n";

while(my $file = readdir DIR) {
    next unless(-f File::Spec->catfile($dir, $file));
    next if($file =~ m/^\./);

    my $fullpath = File::Spec->rel2abs($file);
    my $fullsize = -s File::Spec->catfile($dir, $file);
    my $fullid   = sha256_hex($fullpath);

    my %hash = (
        path    =>  $fullpath,
        size    =>  $fullsize,
        id      =>  $fullid,
    );

    push(@AoH, \%hash);
}
my @array;
for my $i(0..$#AoH) {
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    my ($ext) = $AoH[$i]{path} =~ (/(\.[^.]+)$/);
    my $idext = $AoH[$i]{id} . $ext;
    push(@checksumfiles, $idext);
    push(@array, $AoH[$i]{path});
}

Archive::Tar->create_archive($archive, COMPRESS_GZIP, @array);
#print Archive::Tar->list_archive($archive, COMPRESS_GZIP), "\n";

for my $i(0..$#array) {
    $tar->rename($array[$i], $checksumfiles[$i]);
}

print Dumper sort \@array;
print Dumper sort \@checksumfiles;
#print Dumper sort \@AoH;
```

Comment: crosspost: (https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1205210) please mention crossposts to save people work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The archive is created with the *Class method* `create_archive`, while the [rename](https://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html#%24tar-%3erename(-%24file%2c-%24new_name-)) method is called on the object to (my emphasis)

> Rename the file of the **in-memory** archive to $new_name.

Alas, since the object was never used to write/read the archive there is no in-memory archive.

In general, you can read an archive from disk into memory, where you get [Archive::Tar::File](https://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar/File.html) objects. Then rename the files and write out a new archive.

```
my @file_objs = $tar->read($archive);

for my $i (0..$#file_objs) {
    $file_objs[$i]->rename($checksumfiles[$i]);
}
$tar->write('RENAMED_' . $archive, COMPRESS_GZIP);
```

This worked in my tests.

But this is terribly wasteful if you are indeed first creating the archive, with an extra write-and-read. A suitable way to build the archive in-memory is with [add_files](https://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html#$tar-%3Eadd_files%28-@filenamelist-%29)

```
# In a sub to make sure that renaming stays in order in which files are added
sub archive_renamed {
    my ($archive_name, $orig, $new) = @_;
    if (@$orig != @$new) {
        warn "Unequal length of filename lists";
        return;
    }
    my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;

    for my $file (@$orig) {
        if (not $tar->add_files($file)) {
            warn "Error adding $file: ", $tar->error;             
            return;
        }
    }
    my @file_objs = $tar->get_files;

    for my $i (0..$#file_objs) {
        $file_objs[$i]->rename($new->[$i]);
    }

    $tar->write($archive_name, COMPRESS_GZIP);
    if (my $error = $tar->error) {
        warn "Error writing $archive_name: $error";
        return;
    }
    return 1;
}

archive_renamed('RENAMED_'.$archive, \@array, \@checksumfiles);
```

Files are renamed in the same order as they were added so all files must have been indeed added or we can end up with *wrong* names. Thus we abort on any error in adding files. That is why this needs to  be in a sub, too, so that changes can't slip in so to end up renaming files out of order.

If this ends up in a module use [Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html)::`carp` instead of `warn`. If the main code shouldn't proceed on errors use `die` (or `Carp::croak` in a module) instead.

If particular properties mentioned in the docs for this method pose a problem (they shouldn't), you can even first copy the files with the new names and form the archive with those (then delete them).  That is also extra work but incomparably more efficient than extra reading and writing of archives.

Comment: What other approaches would you consider? This is my first time programming with file compression.

Comment: @JonathanDewein  Updated with a better way if the archive doesn't already exist (while you can also even just copy files with new names first).  Thank you for the attribution.